# Checking assumptions in linear mixed effect model with binary predictor, continuous output

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, residuals

I have a linear mixed effect model I am fitting using `lmer`:

```
lmm <- lmer(output ~ flag + (1 | subject), data = data, REML = TRUE)
```

where `output` is a continuous, real-valued number, `flat` is a binary, categorical predictor, and `subject` is a discrete, categorical ID#.

I am attempting to check that I am not violating the assumptions of this mixed effect model graphically, but I'm not sure if the categorical predictor is skewing my interpretation of these plots.

Do these look like they require further transformations on the dependent variable? And if so, what transformations would be recommended?

(1) Residuals randomly distributed with constant variance

```
plot(lmm)
```

[image: residuals]

(2) Checking normality of residuals:

```
qqnorm(residuals(lmm))
qqline(residuals(lmm))
```

[image: normality]

Comment: The 2nd plot suggests that there may be floor and ceiling effects. Was this the case?

Comment: Log transformed output variable so output is > 0.